# mysql one is to many rquery

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many

table: lead_salesperson

```
------------------------
id    | sp_id   |  phone
------------------------
0     | 1       |  12345678
1     | 1       |  87654321
```

table: productProperties

```
------------------------------------------------
product  | sp_id    |  phone    | activity_name
------------------------------------------------
0        | 1        |  12345678 | vm
1        | 1        |  12345678 | DNC
2        | 1        |  87654321 | SCB 
3        | 1        |  77654321 | SCB
```

```
Select DISTINCT(l.phone) as phone 
  from lead_salesperson as l 
  join lead_activity as ls 
  on (ls.phone=l.phone) && (ls.year_make=l.year_make) && (ls.make=l.make) 
 where l.sp_id=$sp_id and ((ls.act_name!='DNC') OR (ls.act_name!='DNC_AUTO'))
```

so the output should be `87654321,77654321`

I am trying to get all phone numbers that do not have a DNC or DNC_AUTO ... the leadactivity has can have multi rows connected to one row in lead_salesperson . IF even one of the rows (phone) has a DNC or DNC _AUTO in the activity_name then i do not want that phone to be part of the result set any ideas...how to solve this.

Comment: please add the schema of your tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this with a subquery that defines the phones that you want to exclude:

```
select distinct phone
from lead_activity as ls
where act_name in ('DNC', 'DNC_AUTO')
```

Now, you can use this query as a condition:

```
select distinct
    l.phone as phone
from
    lead_salesperson as l
where
    phone not in (
        select distinct phone 
        from lead_activity as ls 
        where act_name in ('DNC', 'DNC_AUTO'))
```

Hope this helps you